# Unexpected token ! at Object../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/animations.js

Tags: angular, animation

I added BrowserAnimationsModule to my app.module.ts file of Angular 6 project. But by doing so, it cause the problem.

```
//app.module.ts
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform- 
 browser/animations';
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HmCG.jpg)

Comment: Can you reproduce issue on stackblitz please?

Comment: problem is because I imported BrowserAnimationsModule. If i remove that line it automatically resolves. Please help.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Add your package.json please.

Comment: Thank For you hints help. @angular/animations was missing in my package.json. Now its fixed. :) thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use,  `npm i @angular/animations --save`

So this will be added to your package.json,

```
"@angular/animations": "^7.1.3",
```

You can also double check your dependencies by using, `npm audit`